# Passing two parameters to testng test @Test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

Code Snippet:

```
@Test
 @Parameters({"a,b"})
 public void submitLogin(String a , String b){
//Code here
    }
```

Error Displayed in Console:
Method submitLogin requires 2 parameters but 1 were supplied in the @Test annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you think that you are trying to pass one parameter "a,b" instead of two "a","b"?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Parameters annotation before Test one. And each parameter should be quotation marked.

```
@Parameters({"a","b"})
@Test
 public void submitLogin(String a , String b){
//Code here
    }
```

Comment: There is no difference in which order annotations are set.

Answer (score 1):

The @Parameters allows you to specify the parameter names, whose value you put in the testng.xml file; Each parameter name must be a string. In your case you clubbed both the parameter names[ a, b] into one single String. The solution would be:

```
@Test
@Parameters({"a", "b"})
public void submitLogin(String a , String b){
    //Code here
}
```

And in your testng.xml define values for these variables as :

```
<parameter name="a" value="foo"/>
<parameter name="b" value="bar"/>
```

And yes, the order of annotations, @Parameters and @Test should not matter.